# One area of confusion on technical test

Tags: api, post, xmlhttprequest, csrf, content-type

I just graduated from a front-end development bootcamp and am experiencing my very first technical test. It all seems very straightforward with the exception of one aspect that I'm hoping to get some opinions on. I'm not quite sure what the company is asking here and was wondering if anyone might be able to interpret it better?

I am to recreate the profile section (name, email, etc.) of a webpage with HTML and CSS, which I understand how to do. There's a JavaScript component involving an HTTP POST request that I'm confused about. There are backend APIs that perform the changing of the profile section.

I was not given the URL for the AJAX call, and was instead provided with the following instructions: "can comment out the actual line that makes AJAX call. Simply assume that you’ll get 200 response with empty string as body. Assume csrf_token to be #####". I've been provided the numbers but have omitted them. Additionally, there was also this line: "the backend API accepts POST request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded body".

In my bootcamp I had not done any POST requests, only GET. Is anyone able to provide some guidance on what exactly this question is asking for? My first step would be to use POSTMAN but without a URL, not sure how to go about this.

EDIT:

From various Googling on how these requests are made, I've so far come up with the below code but still missing a lot (probably). The idea is that if a user were to enter in a new email (or new name, password, etc.), a POST request will be made to make this update.

I've been informed that I'm not allowed to use any jQuery for this test, so I've been trying to learn how to do this in JavaScript alone. Additionally, I'm also not sure where the csrf_token comes in.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = /* URL */;
var params = ;

xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};

xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you don't actually have to make the request, only have its place ready in code, maybe commented out. Your code should have a hard-coded 200 OK "response" from the API with an empty body, indicating that changing the profile worked. So that one line that actually makes the request could be replaced with something like a mock object for the request result and you could use that (but the text says the response is empty anyway, so you don't need to mock a lot).

I think your code should still show (in a comment, or in preceding request setup lines before the actual commented out request) how you would make the request, how you would pass the csrf token, how you would set the content-type of the request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if anything needs to be done (probably not), and how you would pass parameters in that format.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, this definitely provided me with a direction on where to begin. I've made an edit to my question and added in the code I've managed to come up with and also a bit more info on what this request is supposed to do. Since the bootcamp I took primarily used jQuery, not being allowed to do so for this test adds an extra layer of complexity for me. It'd be greatly appreciated if you could provide some additional guidance based on my edits.